# Heron's formula when side lengths include radicals

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I am helping a 7th grade student prepare for a math contest. I have a copy of a previous year's test, and one of the questions has me perplexed! I think perhaps I'm making this problem harder than it needs to be. Here's the problem:

**Find the area of a triangle with sides $2$, $\sqrt{2}$, and $\sqrt{3}-1$.**

I would think we'd need to use Heron's formula here, but it gets so messy with all the radicals. This is a problem that she would be expected to solve in 3 minutes or less, so the simpler I can explain it to her, the better. This is a middle school contest, with most students currently enrolled in Algebra 1, so I don't want a solution using trigonometry.

Comment: Heron's will do, just simplify the resulting terms like $(a+b)(a-b)$ to $a^2-b^2$ first.

Comment: That was my thought, but I couldn't get the terms to work out to the (a+b) (a-b) form, so I'm evidently making a mistake somewhere along the line.

Comment: Is there a reasonable way for a 7th grader to guess that the $2,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}-1$ triangle is a $1,\sqrt{3},2$ right triangle with a $1,1,\sqrt{2}$ right triangle removed? This would make calculating the area easy, but it's hard to see that when you start working on the problem.

Comment: Ah, I never thought of it that way! I don't think she would guess that, but it's definitely a great way to approach it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 7th grader who does not know Heron's formula can still solve this.

Consider the right triangles with two common vertices $A$ and $B$:

- triangle $ABC$ with $AB=1$, $AC=1$, $BC=\sqrt{2}$; its area is $1/2$.

  triangle $ABD$ with $AB=1$, $AD=\sqrt{3}$, $BD=2$; its area is $\sqrt{3}/2$.

Drawing a sketch of these triangles, with point $C$ between $A$ and $D$, we see that the sought-for area is the *difference* of the above areas, $ABD$ minus $ABC$; i.e. it's the area of triangle $BCD$, which is $\sqrt{3}/2-1/2$.

Comment: I really like this method! I think this is how I'll show her how to do it. When I taught her Heron's formula today, she said she probably wouldn't remember that during the contest, and she's pretty good at assessing what works for her. She would definitely understand this method, and it would probably help her with other problems as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

We can use [the fourth form of Heron's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula#Trigonometric_proof_using_the_law_of_cosines) to get an easy answer.

---

Let $a=2, b=\sqrt{2}, c=\sqrt{3}-1$. We can use the formula $$A=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}$$ We have $a^2 = 4, b^2 = 2, c^2 =4-2\sqrt{3}$Thus, $$A=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{32-(2+2\sqrt{3})^2}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{8-(1+\sqrt{3})^2}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$$

Comment: Excellent--that makes it much easier to work with. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The semi-perimeter is $\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ so Heron's formula gives:

$$
\begin{align}
4 A & = \sqrt{(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) \cdot (-3+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) \cdot (1-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) \cdot (3+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})} \\
 & = \sqrt{\big((1+\sqrt{3})^2-2\big) \cdot \big(2-(3-\sqrt{3})^2\big)} \\
 & = \sqrt{(2+2\sqrt{3})(-10+6\sqrt{3})} = \sqrt{16-8\sqrt{3}} = 2 \sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
$$

Denesting the latter radical gives $4A=2(\sqrt{3}-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach not using Heron formula. Let's call $x$ the angle oposite to the side $\sqrt{3}-1$, so using Cosine rule we get:

$$(\sqrt{3}-1)^2=4+2-2\cdot 2\cdot \sqrt{2}\cos x \Rightarrow \cos x=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{8}}\Rightarrow \sin x=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{8}}$$

and then the area is:

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{8}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$$